# How can I auto submit an iframe with post params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on `example.com`, when some one logged on my site I would also want to check his authentication on `abc.com`, abc.com accepts POST request to check authentication.

I was thinking to use an iframe which auto submit a request to abc.com (along with exaple.com ) and set a cookie in abc.com domain too.

1. Please suggest me if there is any better way to handle this?
2. Could some one reply with an example how to submit an iframe with post params?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create a form, submit it to iframe. that however won't be the end to your problems.

Comment: You can't set cookies cross domains via frames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that `iFrame` is the best practice here, but you can render a form inside your `iFrame` and submit it onload.
Of course you will need to pass some data to the form, so you can pass it via the `src` url with query string params and grab it inside the `iFrame`.
For `post` request you will need to set the form (inside the iFrame) as `method="post"`

Comment: Thanks @sag1v I will check this

Answer (score 0):

You can set a form's target attribute to submit to an iframe:

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="http://someurl.com" method="post" target="myiframe">
```

You may also consider just using an ajax call with jQuery instead and set the httpmethod to "post", which is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks @baldprogrammer